# Linear Algebra and Combinatorics

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics

Let $F \subset 2^{[n]}$,where $[n] = \{1,...,n\}$. And $\forall A \in F :|A| = 1 \mod 2$. And $ \forall A,B \in F: A \neq B \to |A \cap B| = 0 \mod 2 $

**Prove** that $|F| \leq n$

I use linear algebra's method to prove the statement.

Let $|F| > n$. For all elements $ A_i \in F$ we assign vector $v_i \in \{1,0\}^n $

So $|F| > n$. Hence $\{ v_i \}$ are linearly dependent. Hence, $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_{|F|} \in \mathbb{R}: \sum_{i = 1}^{|F|} \lambda_i v_i = 0$ and $\exists \lambda_i \neq 0, i \in \{1,...,|F|\}$

Therefore,
$$ 0 = ( \sum_{i = 1}^{|F|} \lambda_i v_i )^2 =  \sum_{i = 1}^{|F|} (\lambda_i v_i )^2  +  \sum_{i \neq j} \lambda_i v_i \lambda_j v_j = 
\sum_{i = 1}^{|F|} \lambda_i ^2|A_i| +  \sum_{i \neq j} \lambda_i v_i \lambda_j v_j $$

I need to show that obtained sum is not equal 0.

So $ \sum \lambda_i ^ 2 > 0 $ and $|A_i| > 0$. Hence $\sum_{i = 1}^{|F|} \lambda_i ^2|A_i|$ > 0.

But I don't know what we can say about second part of the sum.

Comment: I think it is more natural to try to show linear independence over $ \mathbb{F}_2 $ than $ \mathbb{R} $.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an elaboration of my comment. The point is to consider the vectors in $ (\mathbb{F}_2)^n $ over the field $ \mathbb{F}_2 $

Let $ F = \{ A_1, A_2, \ldots A_m \} $ and for $ i = 1,2, \ldots, m $ let $ v_i \in (\mathbb{F}_2)^n $ be the incidence vector for the subset $ A_i $ as usual. Our goal is to show that $ m \le n $ and to show this it suffices to show that $ \{ v_i, 1 \le i \le m \} $ is a linearly independent set over $ \mathbb{F}_2 $. Let $ \langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle $ denote the standard inner product in $ \mathbb{F}_2 $ and observe that $ \langle v_i, v_j \rangle = \delta_{ij} $.

Suppose that $$ \alpha_1 v_1 + \alpha_2 v_2 + \ldots + \alpha_m v_m = 0 $$ where the $ \alpha_i $ are in $ \mathbb{F}_2 $. Then, we have for each $ j $, $$ \langle \sum_{i=1}^{m} \alpha_i v_i, v_j \rangle = \alpha_j \langle v_j, v_j \rangle = \alpha_j = 0 $$ meaning that the vectors are indeed linearly independent over $ \mathbb{F}_2 $. But, $ \dim_{\mathbb{F}_2} (\mathbb{F}_2)^n = n $, so $ m \le n $.